# Remove Value from ArrayData

Tags: jqgrid

I have a grid where I can access the rowData with

```
var rowData = $('#gridtbl').getRowData(rowId);
```

However, not all values from the rowData is required and I need to pass this to a Controller. How can I manipulate the ArrayData to remove a certain element from it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That depends upon what you would like to remove...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to remove element from array.

```
var list = [1,2,3];
alert(list.splice(1, 1)); // will show 2
alert(list):
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. The ArrayData returned from jqgrid    getRowData(rowId) doesn't like slice or splice.

Comment: whats the data which is being returned ?

Comment: {"SelectedItem":"Test","ProcessStatus":"In Process","OrderID":"1234","ItemNo":"5","Color":"Blue","Date":"06/18/2012"}

Lets say I want to remove "ProcessStatus" from the dataset.